# Why `this` point to `window` object in an Ember DS.Model?

Tags: ember.js

I've just encountered a very weird situation:

In a DS.Model like this one:

```
App.Event = DS.Model.extend
  date: DS.attr 'string'
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  startAt: DS.attr 'string'
  endAt: DS.attr 'string'
  startTime: (->
    moment(@startAt).format 'L'  # PAY ATTENTION AT HERE
  ).property @startAt            # AND HERE
```

This piece of code actually works, but if I change `@startAt` to `@get 'startAt'`, then `this` will no longer point to `DS.Model`'s instance but instead point to `window` object!

Here're two debugging screenshot:

[image]

[image]

How did this even happened??? I've put this code online: http://jsfiddle.net/nightire/EJqRA/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know coffeescript but I guess your problem is will be solved by replacing

```
App.Event = DS.Model.extend
  date: DS.attr 'string'
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  startAt: DS.attr 'string'
  endAt: DS.attr 'string'
  startTime: (->
    moment(@get 'startAt').format 'L'
  ).property @get('startAt')
```

to

```
 App.Event = DS.Model.extend
  date: DS.attr 'string'
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  startAt: DS.attr 'string'
  endAt: DS.attr 'string'
  startTime: (->
    moment(@get 'startAt').format 'L'
  ).property('startAt')
```